# Let f : R → R be a continuous function such that f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y), ∀x, y ∈ R

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let f : R → R be a continuous function such that f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y),
∀x, y ∈ R
Prove that for every x ∈ R and λ real: f(λx) = λf(x)

Comment: Have you taken a linear algebra course? If so, hint: prove that $f$ is linear.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk that's just a translation of what is asked for...

Comment: Put $ f(1)=\lambda$.

Comment: @Learning I don't think I agree. Of course after the fact we will know that $f$ is linear; or else this would be a misleading hint! But the point of my hint is that one can show that $f$ has the desired form by using the already-known classification of linear maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. In particular, I'm not sure how to break down the problem into anything simpler than this idea without giving away the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \bullet $ First of all $ f\left(0\right)=f\left(0+0\right)=f\left(0\right)+f\left(0\right) $, thus $ f\left(0\right)=0 \cdot $

Let $ x\in\mathbb{R} $ :

$ \bullet $ If $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, then $ f\left(nx\right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(f\left(\left(k+1\right)x\right)-f\left(kx\right)\right)}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{f\left(x\right)}=n f\left(x\right) \cdot $

$ \bullet $ If $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, then $ 0=f\left(0\right)=f\left(nx-nx\right)=f\left(nx\right)+f\left(-nx\right) $, thus $ f\left(-nx\right)=-f\left(nx\right) \cdot $

$ \bullet $ Hence, if $ n\in\mathbb{Z}_{-} $, then $ f\left(nx\right)=-f\left(-nx\right)=-\left(-n\right)f\left(x\right)=n f\left(x\right) \cdot $

Thus : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}\right),\ f\left(nx\right)=n f\left(x\right) $$

$ \bullet $ If $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, then $ f\left(x\right)=f\left(n\times\frac{x}{n}\right)=nf\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) $, thus $ f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}f\left(x\right) \cdot $

$ \bullet $ Hence, if $ \left(p,q\right)\in\left(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}^{*}\right) $, then $ f\left(\frac{p}{q}x\right)=pf\left(\frac{x}{q}\right)=\frac{p}{q}f\left(x\right) \cdot $

Thus : $$ \left(\forall q\in\mathbb{Q}\right),\ f\left(qx\right)=q f\left(x\right) $$

Let $ \lambda\in\mathbb{R} $ :

Since $ \mathbb{Q} $ is dense in $ \mathbb{R} $, there exists $ \left(\lambda_{n}\right)_{n}\in\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}} $ such that $ \lambda_{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\lambda \cdot $ And we have the following : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ f\left(\lambda_{n}x\right)=\lambda_{n}f\left(x\right) $$

Since $ f $ is continuous, $ \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{f\left(\lambda_{n}x\right)}=f\left(\lambda x\right) $, thus, taking $ n $ to infinity we get : $$ f\left(\lambda x\right)=\lambda f\left(x\right) $$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Step 1: Prove $f(nx)=nf(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Step 2: Prove $f(qx)=qf (x)$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$

Step 3: For the case real number $r\in\mathbb{R}$, use a sequence of rational numbers converge to $r$ and use the continuity of $f$.

Comment: I think step 2 should say $q \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Yes, I correct the typo. Thanks!